# How do I write an apology scene?

Tags: fiction, publishing, fan-fiction

I need to write a scene where someone apologizes to a girl for physically hurting her. But I’m confused on how to start it. They are in school, and the boy makes time to talk to her. And it is in the girl’s POV. Can someone please help me, preferably with an example?

Comment: Close-Voters: it would be nice if you could explain to a new user that you are voting to put their question on hold. They can't see those votes and rarely know what it means. @Alison: To explain a bit about what seems to have happened here: apparently five community members with more than 500 reputation thought your question was off-topic and asking us what you should write, which is why your question is temporarily put on hold. An [edit] from you would automatically send it to a special reopen review queue where it would take 5 other members to reopen the question.

Comment: I understood your question to be a general question for "What things should I keep in mind when writing an apology scene?" If that's right, could you [edit] and maybe remove the example request? That may have given people the impression that this was a "Please tell me what to write" request instead of "How should you in general do this, perhaps illustrated by a *generic* example?" Also, if you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Taking the tour gives you a badge, too ;) Have fun on the site!

Comment: I don't see why anyone would want to close that Question yet why is it difficult for you? Broadly, you put yourself into the character, and say what the character would say; Is the problem that you can't think of suitable words, or that you don't believe the character was wrong?